# How to Combine "OpenAds" Admob with Splash?

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an admob ad of the "open ad" type.

Which works when the application is started, and unfortunately the application is often rejected because the advertisement is seen before the content of the application ....

So I put Splash_Activity to appear a little and then the ad appears, the method is effective and the application is accepted.

**Problem:** When the time I set for Splash_Activity expires, the ad disappears with it without the need to press continue for the application, and in this case the ad remains in the background of the application.

**Required:** The Splash_Activity screen stops when the ad appears and does not disappear unless you close the ad.

> AppOpenManager:

```
public class AppOpenManager implements LifecycleObserver, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenManager";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-****/****";
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private long loadTime = 0;

    private AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback loadCallback;
    private Activity currentActivity;
    private static boolean isShowingAd = false;

    private final GlobalVar Splash_Activity;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public AppOpenManager(GlobalVar splash_Activity) {
        this.Splash_Activity = splash_Activity;
        this.Splash_Activity.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    /** LifecycleObserver methods */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
    public void onStart() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showAdIfAvailable();

            }
        }, 1500);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStart");
    }

    /** Shows the ad if one isn't already showing. */
    public void showAdIfAvailable() {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

            FullScreenContentCallback fullScreenContentCallback =
                    new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                            AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = null;
                            isShowingAd = false;
                            fetchAd();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            isShowingAd = true;
                        }
                    };

            appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback);
            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");
            fetchAd();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Request an ad
     */
    public void fetchAd() {


        // Have unused ad, no need to fetch another.
        if (isAdAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        loadCallback =
                new AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                     *
                     * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        AppOpenManager.this.appOpenAd = ad;
                        AppOpenManager.this.loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                     *
                     * @param loadAdError the error.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                    }

                };
        AdRequest request = getAdRequest();
        AppOpenAd.load(
                Splash_Activity, AD_UNIT_ID, request,
                AppOpenAd.APP_OPEN_AD_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, loadCallback);
    }
    // We will implement this below.


    /**
     * Creates and returns ad request.
     */
    private AdRequest getAdRequest() {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }

    /**
     * Utility method that checks if ad exists and can be shown.
     */
    public boolean isAdAvailable() {
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = null;
    }
    /** Utility method to check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
        long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - this.loadTime;
        long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }
}
```

> Splash_Activity

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (go) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash_Activity.this, home_main.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 4200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a callback listener to know when the ad has been dismissed, and stop further code execution until then.

```
    public interface AdListener {
        void onCompleted();
    }
```

Change the code of `showAdIfAvailable` like below with a parameter of listener.

```
    public void showAdIfAvailable(@NonNull AdListener listener) {
        // Only show ad if there is not already an app open ad currently showing
        // and an ad is available.
        if (!isShowingAd && isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");
            appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() 
                    this.appOpenAd = null;
                    isShowingAd = false;
                    fetchAd();

                    // Inform caller that we have done
                    listener.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                    appOpenAd = null;
                    // Inform caller that we have done
                    listener.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    isShowingAd = true;
                }
            });
            appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can not show ad.");

            // Inform caller that we have done
            listener.onCompleted();

            // Load new ad
            fetchAd();
        }
    }
```

Call to show app onen ad like below from SplashActivity:

```
showAdIfAvailable(SplashActivity.this, new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                
                // Start your activity from here
                
            }
        });
```

However, this is a demonstration of the process. Change it as you want to use it.

Hope it will help.